# Is there a better way of .Core 3.1 many-to-many inserting

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, many-to-many, insert-update

My clients uploading excel file for product updates. Each excel file has 50k+ rows with ProductId and multiple SpecId.

For every single row i'm doing like;

```
Product p = _context.Products.include(i => i.Specs).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == ExcelProductId);
Spec s = _context.Specs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == ExcelSpecId);
p.Specs.Add(s);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

This is causing some performance issues and code really messes up with 25+ specs. Do we have a better way for doing this? Like inserting only Id values into ProductSpec many-to-many table? Maybe with SqlBulkCopy or AdoNet?

i really need good advices :(

Thank you!

Comment: Hey, can you maybe share what your database classes look like? Becuase for a many-to-many-relationship you usually have three classes. For example Product, Spec and then a third connecting class like ProductSpec.

Comment: *Like inserting only Id values into ProductSpec many-to-many table* -- Yes.

Comment: The EF core contains the Bulk insert extension, you could try to use the BulkInsert method to insert data. More detail information, please check the following links: [Bulk insert](https://entityframeworkcore.com/saving-data-bulk-insert), [BulkInsert on Nested one-to-many relationship](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions/issues/176) and [EFCore.BulkExtensions](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions).

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT Not EF-core. You refer to 3rd-party software.

Answer (score 0):

You could

1. Apply batching, where you send in parts at a time (e.g. you read 1000 rows, insert them, read, another 1000 etc). Doing this in an async matter to not block the main ui thread (if this is a gui app).
2. Using [bulk inserting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)  there is also a way to [bulk insert xml files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-import-and-export-of-xml-documents-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=When%20you%20bulk%20import%20XML,specified%20in%20the%20XML%20declaration.). If the file does not match your table's structure completely, you can try to first insert everything to a staging table, and then run an sql query to copy the data over. There also seem to be [nuget packages](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions).
3. Create a custom sql query that is optimized for this task. You can use the Sql profiler to get insight into the query that EF generates, and there should be many resources on how to write efficient SQL queries online.